# Using Yboss gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone show me an example of how to use the yboss Gem in rails? I know how to run it in IRB, but I dunno how to incorporate into a rails app

i've already

```
bundle install
```

And then I tried to use (in def index of the controller)

```
YBoss::Config.instance.oauth_key = 'your consumer_key here'
YBoss::Config.instance.oauth_secret = 'your consumer_secret here'
```

But I get name error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add gem to Gemfile
2. run `bundle install`
3. Put [configuration](https://github.com/elcamino/yboss#configuration) to initializer
4. run `rails server`

Do you still get name error?